# Spring security custom user details @Id issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot API having Spring Security to register and Login.

```java
@Entity
public class Users{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String userid;


    @Email
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String username;

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_WRITE)
    private String password;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
    public boolean enabled;
```

**Dao class**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<Users, String> {
    public Users findDistinctByUsername(String username);
}
```

**Controller**

```
Users user = userdao.findDistinctByUsername(username);
```

When I use username as @Id it is working fine, but if i user userid as @Id, I'm getting an error

**error:**
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [public java.lang.String com.example.demo.Model.Users.username] by reflection for persistent property [com.example.demo.Model.Users#username] : T1EzQkExUU41Tg; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [public java.lang.String com.example.demo.Model.Users.username] by reflection for persistent property [com.example.demo.Model.Users#username] : T1EzQkExUU41Tg",

T1EzQkExUU41Tg: userid

Comment: What is the data type of user id in the database

Comment: UserId: Varchar

Answer (score 0):

When you are using @id on String then you have to specify the generation type otherwise it take default auto increment from database as int. That's why you got error.

```
@id
private int id;
```

you will have do define your own custom generator for string attribute.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(//add the generation type here)
private Long id;
```

Comment: I'm manually generating Id at service level, that's why I have not used @GeneratedValue